# Operating system incompatibility while trying to install dc2

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

After I installed a fresh copy of Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition on a server and joined it to our domain, I wanted to promote it to be the second domain controller in our domain.

While trying to do so, I got the following error message:
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What's the OS and operational level of your primary DC (2000, 2003, 2008?)

Comment: Is your first domain controller a Windows 2008 R2 system by any chance? If so then I'd suggest that the error message means what it says and says what it means.

Answer (score 2):

Your are trying to promote a Windows Server 2008 (v6.0) server to Domain Controller of a Active Directory 2008 R2 (v6.1) deployment, the other Domain Controller(s) must be Server 2008 R2.

Server 2008 R2 is a completely new OS from Server 2008 (as much as Win7 is to Vista anyway). Despite the poor naming choice, which especially ignored that Server 2003 R2 was essentially a feature pack upgrade to Server 2003, they are not compatible in many ways.

Comment: When you install 2008R2 you're given the option of selecting the version of Ad you want. If 2008R2 was selected then adding a 2008 non-R2 or older DC is simply not possible. Ever.